# using variables from async operation in an angular template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

so am trying to basically get user details after they login, but am facing issues due to request to get the details taking so long.. It breaks everything. I am not exactly sure, but I believe it's due to the variable being undefined the moment of the template being loaded... What can I do to avoid that?

```
onLogin() {
    if (this.loginPassword === '' || this.loginUsername === '') {
      return false;
    }
    this.loading = true;
    this.auth.login(this.loginUsername, this.loginPassword)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        // Store the access token in the localstorage
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.access_token);
        this.auth.getUserData().subscribe((ele) => {
          console.log(ele, 'ele');
        });
        this.loading = false;
        // Navigate to home page
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }, (err: any) => {
        // This error can be internal or invalid credentials
        // You need to customize this based on the error.status code
        this.loading = false;
        this.error = true;
      });
  }
```

my Login function, after it navigates to the dashboard that's when everything goes south...

```
  getUserData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.globals.baseAPIUrl + 'details', this.cf.requestOptions()).pipe(
      map(res => res)
    );
  }
```

The function I use to get the user details, which takes so long and messes everything up...

```
this.auth.getUserData().subscribe((ele) => {
      this.globals = ele;
    });
```

How am getting the values for the dashboard and saving them

```
<div class="page-title-heading">
      <div class="page-title-icon" style="height: 150px; width: 130px;">
        <img src="{{ globals.userPhoto }}" alt="Raised image" class="img-fluid rounded card-img-top-img shadow-lg"
          style="height: auto;">
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ globals.userName }}
        <div class="page-title-subheading">
          {{ globals.designation }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is how am calling them in the HTML template

```
Cannot read property 'userPhoto ' of undefined
```

I keep getting this error though, any help would be great...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are navigating to the new route before the response from getUserData() is received and the value is stored in `globals`.

You can fix this by navigating to the home page within the subscription of getUserData

```js
onLogin() {
    if (this.loginPassword === '' || this.loginUsername === '') {
      return false;
    }
    this.loading = true;
    this.auth.login(this.loginUsername, this.loginPassword)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        // Store the access token in the localstorage
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.access_token);
        this.auth.getUserData().subscribe((ele) => {
          console.log(ele, 'ele');
          // is this where you intend to set globals?

          this.loading = false;
          // Navigate to home page
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        });
      }, (err: any) => {
        // This error can be internal or invalid credentials
        // You need to customize this based on the error.status code
        this.loading = false;
        this.error = true;
      });
  }
```

Though, I have to say that it isn't clear to me where you intend on setting globals. Also, the nested subscribes can be refactored to use `switchMap` instead, so that is follows the pattern:

```js
this.auth.login(this.loginUsername, this.loginPassword)
  .pipe(
    tap(res => localStorage.setItem(...)),
    catchError(err => /* error handling */),
    switchMap(res => this.auth.getUserData())
  )
  .subscribe(ele => {
    this.loading = false;
    this.globals = ele;
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  });
```

Comment: yea that worked like a charm! As for setting globals I basically do that on almost every component just to keep tabs at the user details all throughout the app